# Convert javascript code into coffescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, rickshaw

Im currently working with Dashing and I need to convert javascript code into coffescript in order to make use of rickshaw graph library. (According to the source code on this website http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/x_axis.html)

I'm trying to have a customized x axis on the graph.

Default Coffescript code= `x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X(graph: @graph)`

JS code to be converted

```
var format = function(n) {

    var map = {
        0: 'zero',
        1: 'first',
        2: 'second',
        3: 'third',
        4: 'fourth'
    };

    return map[n];
}

var x_ticks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X( {
    graph: graph,
    tickFormat: format
} );
```

Into coffescript

```
    var format = function(n) {

    var map = {
        0: 'zero',
        1: 'first',
        2: 'second',
        3: 'third',
        4: 'fourth'
    };

    return map[n];
}


    x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X(graph: @graph,tickFormat: format)//Make use of format
```

Comment: what exactly do you need help with? more importantly, what do you want?

Comment: I want to be able to use

 x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X(graph: @graph,tickFormat: format)  , so what should format function look like in order to look like coffescript?

Comment: that didn't help.. what is the problem? why can't you use rickshaw?

Comment: I want to be able to use customized x axis

Comment: I'm using Rickshaw in Coffescript. So I need to know the syntax for how to define a function that does exactly what format does in coffescript syntax

Comment: Javascript is not allowed when using dashing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
format = (n)->

  map =
    0: 'zero',
    1: 'first',
    2: 'second',
    3: 'third',
    4: 'fourth'
  map[n]
```

Comment: just take out all the redundant syntax in javascript and you have coffeescript.